# Kotlin interface, sending data between two fragments

Tags: android, kotlin

I am looking to send a string from `FragmentA` to `FragmentDialog` by means of an interface `Communicator` through my Main Activity (which automatically opens `FragmentDialog`). Some code to illustrate what I have:

```
class FragmentA: Fragment() {

    private lateinit var communicator: Communicator

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_A, container, false)

        val title = "My Title"

        button.setOnClickListener { communicator.passData(title) }

        return view
    }

}
```

```
class FragmentDialog : DialogFragment() {

    var title: String? = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, container, false)
        view.button_close.setOnClickListener { dismiss() }
        title = arguments?.getString("title")
        view.dialog_title.text = title
        return view
    }

}
```

```
interface Communicator {
    fun passData (titleInput: String)
}
```

and in my Main Activity, which extends the interface:

```
private val fragmentDialog = FragmentDialog()
override fun passData(titleInput: String) {
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("title", titleInput)
        fullScreenDialog.arguments = bundle
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fragmentDialog).addToBackStack(null).commit()
}
```

When I click the `button` in `FragmentA`, I want to send the string `title` to `Communicator`, set the XML element with id `dialog_title` in `FragmentDialog` and automatically open the fragment. In fact, this works fine. The issue is that my "back button" in `FragmentDialog`, i.e. `view.button_close.setOnClickListener { dismiss() }` only works exactly once. If I click `button` in `FragmentA` again, `FragmentDialog` opens fine with the correct title still but `button_close` no longer dismisses the dialog. What could be causing this? I am not getting any consol errors.

Comment: Did you try to call beginTransaction().replace() insted of beginTransaction().add() ?

Comment: That and removing `addToBackStack(null)` seems to fix it...